# Is $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$ an H-space or not?

Tags: algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras, classifying-spaces

$\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ is H-space. $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is H-space. Is $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$ an H-space or not?

Comment: I apologize for a slightly off topic question, but I feel like it's relevant. Is $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$ a classifying space? $\mathbb{R}P^\infty=B\mathbb{R}^\times=B\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{C}P^\infty=B\mathbb{C}^\times=BS^1$. Unless I am making some silly mistake, I believe $\mathbb{H}^\times$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^3$. So, I'm led to believe that $\mathbb{H}P^\infty=BSU(2)$. Then, if I'm not mistake, you can use the group operations on $SU(2)$ to endow $\mathbb{H}P^\infty=BSU(2)$ with the structure of an $H$-space. Take this with a huge grain of salt though, I am no topologist.

Comment: Of course my vague argument is that $[X,\mathbb{H}P^\infty]$ should classify $\mathbb{H}$-valued line bundles on $X$, which are just $\mathbb{H}^\times$-torsors, and so it should be the classifying space $B\mathbb{H}^\times$.

Comment: @Alex: yes, all of that is correct.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, well now that a topologist has spoken, I feel much better. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the "you can use the group operations on $SU(2)$ to endow $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty}$ with the structure of an H-space." That is very much not correct. You can of course use them to endow $SU(2)$ itself with the structure of an H-space. The problem, in terms of $\mathbb{H}$-line bundles, is that one cannot take the tensor product of two $\mathbb{H}$-line bundles and get another $\mathbb{H}$-line bundle back because $\mathbb{H}$ is noncommutative.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I was thinking that $B$ is functorial, so the $H$-space diagrams map over to $H$-space diagrams. What goes wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: $B$ is a functor, even a monoidal functor when suitably described, from the category of topological groups to the category of, say, connected topological spaces. But $SU(2)$ is not a group object *in the category of topological groups*; by the Eckmann-Hilton argument, the only topological groups with this property are the commutative ones.

Comment: That is, the group operation $SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SU(2)$ is not a morphism *of topological groups*, and those are the maps that induce maps on classifying spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, I see. I would need to define $H$-space operations on $SU(2)$ where the 'multiplication map' is actually a topological group map.

Comment: Yes, and it's a general fact that if $G$ is a group (or a topological group, or whatever), then the multiplication map $G \times G \to G$ is a group homomorphism iff the multiplication is commutative. This is a corollary of Eckmann-Hilton.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see this. Is very much in the same spirit as to why $H^i(X,G)$ shouldn't be a group, if $G$ is non-commutative. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 8):

First, let me make the weaker claim that $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty}$ is not *naturally* an H-space. The natural H-space structures on $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ resp. $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ come from the fact that they classify isomorphism classes of real resp. complex line bundles, which naturally have group structures given by taking the tensor product. This no longer holds for quaternionic line bundles since $\mathbb{H}$ is no longer commutative, so there's no longer an obvious natural candidate for an H-space structure on $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty}$.

But in fact there is no H-space structure at all. The reason is that, as observed by Alex Youcis in the comments, we have $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty} \cong BSU(2)$ and hence $\Omega \mathbb{HP}^{\infty} \cong SU(2)$, so if $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty}$ had an H-space structure then the H-space structure on $SU(2)$ coming from its Lie group structure would be homotopy commutative by the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). But [Araki, James, and Thomas](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183523594) showed that no compact connected nonabelian Lie group is homotopy commutative as an H-space.

Comment: How did you get from "and hence $\Omega\mathbb{H}P^\infty=SU(2)$" to saying that the group structure on $SU(2)$ would need to be homotopy commutative? I assume you're taking the $H$-space structure on $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$, pushing this structure to $\Omega\mathbb{H}P^\infty=SU(2)$. There I get a little lost, it seems as though you're saying that this new $H$-space structure must 'Eckmann-Hilton intertwine' (I don't know what the phrase is) with the standard structure on $SU(2)$, which would mean it's homotopy commutative. Is that right? If so, why is there 'intertwining'? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: the loop space of an H-space has two H-space structures, one coming from applying the H-space structure pointwise and coming from composing loops. Up to homotopy, these satisfy the conditions of the Eckmann-Hilton argument (this is a straightforward check), so applying the Eckmann-Hilton argument implies that they agree up to homotopy and are homotopy associative and homotopy commutative. This is the same argument you run to show that the H-space structure on a double loop space is homotopy commutative, which implies that $\pi_2$ (and all higher $\pi_n$) are commutative.

Comment: Also, if $X \cong BG$, then $\Omega X \cong G$ as H-spaces.

Comment: I get totally lost...

Comment: @RSQ: are you familiar with the Eckmann-Hilton argument? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument for some details.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I didn't check that the EH condition holds, but I believe you. +1